# Lixo memoria saída função insere no meio de uma lista

Tags: c, lista, lista-encadeada

Pessoal desenvolvi essa função:

```
tipo_lista * insere_meio(tipo_lista *aux, tipo_lista * valor, int pos){
 int cont=1; //é a posição do primeiro elemento da lista encadeada
 tipo_lista * p = aux;
 tipo_lista * novo = (tipo_lista*)malloc(sizeof(tipo_lista));
 while (cont != pos){ //testa se é igual a posição que ele quer inserir
     p = p -> prox;
     cont++;
 }
 novo -> info = valor;
 novo -> prox = p -> prox;
 p -> prox = novo;
 return aux;
}
```

Na `main` chamei:

```
p = insere_meio(p, cria_no(5), (2));
```

Imprime:

```
void imprime_lista(tipo_lista* p)
{
 while (p != NULL)
 {
     printf("%d ", p->info);
     p = p -> prox;
 }
 printf("\n");
}
```

Cria Nó:

```
tipo_lista * cria_no (int valor)
{
 tipo_lista * novo;
 novo = (tipo_lista *)malloc(sizeof(tipo_lista));
 novo -> info = valor;
 novo -> prox = NULL;
 return novo;
}
```

Inseriu corretamente na posição 2, acontece que a impressão do número 5 foi de lixo de memória. Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema para imprimir o número 5 de maneira adequada.

Muito obrigado

Comment: Poderia nos mostrar a função que percorre os nós imprimindo e a que cria os nós?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado já adicionei as funções que necessita.

Comment: Pronto, detectei dois problemas : a) você não deve criar um novo objeto de tipo_lista se já está passando esse valor ; b) `novo->info = valor` está inserindo na informação o endereço de memória do ponteiro `valor`

Comment: Vou elaborar melhor numa resposta isso que eu comentei ; só que posso demorar um pouco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função estava recebendo um nó novo e criando um nó novo dentro dela, ou seja, estava fazendo o processo duas vezes. No caso da minha resposta eu removi o nó que é criado pela função cria_no e é passado como parâmetro e coloquei apena um int no lugar.

```
tipo_lista * insere_meio(tipo_lista *aux, int valor, int pos){
...
...
}
```

E no main:

```
p = insere_meio(p, 5, (2));
```

Outra resposta possível é usando o novo nó que é passado para a função e deixando de criar o `novo` dentro dela.

```
//valor foi mudado para novo, porque neste caso um novo nó é passado e não um valor
tipo_lista * insere_meio(tipo_lista *aux, tipo_lista * novo, int pos){
    int cont=1; //é a posição do primeiro elemento da lista encadeada
    tipo_lista * p = aux;
    //Não é mais necessário criar o novo na próxima linha
    //tipo_lista * novo = (tipo_lista*)malloc(sizeof(tipo_lista));
    while (cont != pos){ //testa se é igual a posição que ele quer inserir
        p = p -> prox;
        cont++;
    }
    //O novo nó já possui o seu valor atribuído
    //novo -> info = valor;
    novo -> prox = p -> prox;
    p -> prox = novo;
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Tem algum motivo para essa mudança? Sua resposta está incompleta

Comment: Coloquei `tipo_lista * valor` em vez de `ìnt valor`.

Comment: Jefferson, editei a resposta explicando melhor o que foi feito.

Comment: André, uma observação, se você tentar inserir na primeira posição a função não funcionará, pois nesse caso você teria que retornar o novo.

Comment: Não deu certo esse último. Para tudo aqui.

Comment: O main fica: p = insere_meio(p, cria_no(5), (2));